# Attach a QToolButton to bottom right corner of the parent QWidget

Tags: qt, pyqt

I am faced with this problem and being a Qt noob am not able to fix it.

Basically, I instantiated a `QToolButton` and parented it to `QTreeWidget`. The `QTreeWidget` is inside a vertical layout and when I try to change the position of the tool button inside the `QTreeWidget` using `QTreeWidget.size()` it gives me very unexpected and wrong results.

Can anyone help me with this? Will deeply appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: Can you describe what the result should look like? Should the button always be in the top left corner within the QTreeWidget?

Comment: First of all sorry for the wrong title. It's not a QDockWidget but a QToolButton.

Comment: I want a button to always stay on the bottom right of my tree widget. Upon resizing the window I will apply event filter to position it accordingly. But since my tree widget is inside a vertical layout, querying the tree widget's size is not giving me correct results. So I am not able to move my button accordingly.

Comment: Thanks :) Sorry for not doing that myself. Is there any way to place it there, though?

Comment: Could you please post the code you've tried using `size()`? How did you handle the resize event? The way I know is sub-classing the widget which event you want to handle and overwrite this event (`resizeEvent(...)` in this case).

Answer (score 3):

You haven't posted any examples of what you are actually doing, but here is how to attach a button to the lower right of the tree widget:

*Edit: I have replaced my answer after seeing that you want to composite the widget OVER the tree*

### Using an eventFilter

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(640,480)

        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)

        self.tree = QtGui.QTreeWidget(self)
        self.tree.installEventFilter(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tree)

        self.button = QtGui.QToolButton(self.tree)
        self.button.setText("FOO")
        self.button.setMinimumSize(100, 30)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self.tree and event.type() == event.Resize:
            self.alignTreeButton()       
        return False

    def alignTreeButton(self):
        padding = QtCore.QSize(5,5) # optional
        newSize = self.tree.size() - self.button.size() - padding
        self.button.move(newSize.width(), newSize.height())          

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    w.raise_()
    app.exec_()
```

The button is just parented to the tree, and we install the event filter on the tree to catch resize events. Once the tree is resized, we take its size, subtract the size of the button, and then move the button.

### Using composition

I believe its more efficient to actually subclass the QTreeWidget, compose it with the QToolButton as a member, and then overload the `resizeEvent()` locally to handle the resize. First off this makes the behavior handling local to the TreeWidget, which is cleaner. Also, I believe it reduces the overhead that an EventFilter would add to your main window. The eventFiler would be a python callable that is called many more times because of it handling every event for the object. Whereas the local resizeEvent() for the TreeWidget is only called during the resize.

```
class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(640,480)

        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)

        self.tree = TreeWidget(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tree)     


class TreeWidget(QtGui.QTreeWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TreeWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.button = QtGui.QToolButton(self)
        self.button.setText("FOO")
        self.button.setMinimumSize(100, 30)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super(TreeWidget, self).resizeEvent(event)
        self.alignTreeButton()

    def alignTreeButton(self):
        padding = QtCore.QSize(5,5) # optional
        newSize = self.size() - self.button.size() - padding
        self.button.move(newSize.width(), newSize.height())
```

Comment: I think, OP wants the button _on_ the tree widget (positioned bottom-right), not under.

Comment: @Avaris: Thanks for pointing that out. Just replaced my example with one that lays the button over the tree widget in the bottom right.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible to set a horizontal box layout for the tree widget then add a spacer and the tool button with bottom alignment.